# SQL query to return items with count sale_id = 4

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

```
user: user_id     | user_name 
Sale: sale_id(pk) | user_id(fk) | sale_amount 
item: item_id(pk) | sale_id(fk)
```

The sale_id is generated everytime a user purchases from the item table.

I wish to generate an output that will written me user_id, sale_id and count(item_id) i.e, total items purchased by a user in separate transaction where count(sale_id) in item table =4.

I tried using this but it does not work:

```
select s.user_id,s.id, count(i.item_id) 
from sale s join item i 
on s.id = i.sale_id 
group by s.use_id, i.sale_id
having count(i.sale_id) = 4
;
```

If a user_id 1 as 2 different transactions where in first transaction(sale_id = 3) he buys 2 items and in second transaction (sale_id = 13) he purchases 4 items which means in the item table each four items purchased will have same sale_id. So, I want to see the output where users have purchased 4 items in one transaction.

output:

```
s.user_id | i.sale_id | count(i.item_id) 
1           13          4
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"?

Comment: the query generates error and does not return any output. Not able to figure out what mistake I am doing.

Comment: I really do not understand those, who ask a question about an error they get while running the code, but do not share the exact error message.

Comment: Ok it doesn't work....but if it worked you probably wouldn't be asking. So please tell us something a bit more useful: what does it do instead? Give us some specific details rather than vague statements. We cannot always guess your error message...and anyway why should we need to? It's like asking a mechanic to guess what is wrong with your car when you already know that the engine is overheating. Also these questions are a lot easier to answer when the asker provides some sample data and also an example of the expected results (based on that data). Thanks

Comment: Apologies people. I was writing the column name incorrectly. On 4th line instead of use_id it is user_id. I rectified it immediately.  Apparently MySQL workbench only says error in the code but does not specify what error. A non-technical person learning some basic analytics. thank you for the help.

Comment: But mysql tells you near which part of the sql statement it found the error. That near part is important.

Answer (score -1):

you have aggregation with respect to `s.user_id,s.id` however you are grouping by `s.user_id, i.sale_id`. This typically causes error because your query is malformed.

furthermore if you put `i.sale_id` into group by and try to use having with `count(i.sale_id) = 4` this never returns results. because `count(i.sale_id)` will always be either 0 or 1 when you group by with sale_id